# CSS3 Scale, Fade and Spin on the same element (why isn't SCALE working?!?)

Tags: css, scale, css-transforms, css-animations

OK noobs. Need this circle to **scale** and **fade** in once at the beginning of the animation (while spinning) and continue to **spin** thereafter. Not that hard right!?! Got the **fade** and **spin** working but **scale** just refuses to work!

Is there a **fat finger** somewhere? Before I rip out what hair I have left,  ***please expose my noobness and why SCALE is not working***? Thank you, that is all...

Latest **FF** only. *(To lazy to code for everything else.)*

[JS Fiddle EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dragontheory/sRdfD/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div
{width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: transparent;
border: solid 10px blue;
border-radius: 50%;
border-top: solid 10px transparent;
border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;

-moz-animation-name: scaleIn,fadeIn,spin;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s,1s,1s;
-moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in,ease-in,linear;
-moz-animation-delay: 0,0,0;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1,1,infinite;
-moz-animation-direction: normal,normal,normal;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards,forwards,forwards;
-moz-animation-play-state: running,running,running;}

@-moz-keyframes scaleIn
{
from    {-moz-transform: scale(2);}
to      {-moz-transform: scale(1);}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn
{
from   {opacity: 0.0;}
to     {opacity: 1.0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes spin
{
from  {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
to    {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `-moz-transform:rotate()` is overriding `-moz-transform:scale()`. They need to be together

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GUCYr/)

```
@-moz-keyframes transformIn {
    from {
        -moz-transform: scale(2) rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

As for how to get it to rotate and scale and then just rotate, you will need to make another `@keyframes`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tC9nz/1/)

```
@-moz-keyframes transformAnim {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -moz-transform:  rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

FYI your `-moz-animation-fill-mode` rule was breaking the 3rd animation for me :s not sure why, remove it seems to work fine.

Comment: Hold up! I need the spinning to NOT stop between the scale and the second rotate animation. So do we need 3 rotate animations?

Comment: That's happening because of `cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000)`, they need to be on the same animation and share the same timing unfortunately. You'll have to use a timing that will flow into the `linear` timing of `transformAnim` more naturally like `ease-in` or `linear`.